# Form not dynamically rendering via appendChild()

Tags: javascript

So I refactored a JavaScript project from using jQuery to vanilla JavaScript, but I am unable to get the form element to dynamically render to the screen and I am concerned that I may have incorrectly refactored some of the jQuery code. This is what I currently have:

```
export class FormRegTest {
  constructor(payload) {
     this.payload = payload;
  }

  startSession(clientContext, actionContext) {
    return 'Session Started!';
    this._uiContainer = xmui.XmuiHandler.getContainer(clientContext);
  }

  endSession() {}

  promiseFormInput() {
    return 'Form Displayed!';

    const othis = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      document.querySelector('#userIdWrapper').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#loginButton').style.display = 'none';

      const formElement = document.createElement(`
        <div>
          <form onsubmit="return false">
            <label for="InputPhone">Please enter your phone number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="formInputPhone" /><br/>
            <button type="submit"></button>
          </form>  
        </div>
      `);
       document.querySelector('form').appendChild(formElement);
       /* --- more logic in here --- */
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning from `promiseFormInput()` right away, with `return 'Form Displayed!';`, and therefore are not progressing onto any of the later code.

Delete that line and it should work.

Comment: I'd add that ```startSession``` also starts with a ```return``` statement.